# Create child class instance from parent class

Tags: ruby

What is the best way of having a parent class create instances of its child class? I figured out ways that work, but don't like them. An example:

```
class MyParentClass
  def do_something
    if condition1
      @child = ChildClass1.new
    else
      @child = ChildCLass2.new
    end
  end
end

class ChildClass1 < MyParentClass
end

class ChildClass2 < MyParentClass
end
```

Comment: Parent-child relation does not seem significant here. It looks like a mere delegation pattern.

Comment: The issue that I'm running into is that if you do the normal `require_relative` method of it would tend towards creating a circular reference (ChildClass1 needs MyParentClass and MyParentClass needs ChildClass1)

Comment: `MyParentClass` does not need `ChildClass1` during definition. It only needs it during runtime. So there is no problem with this order.

Comment: Why do you have to create subclass instance in your parent instance?

Comment: @sawa so the convention would just be to just require all three in any part of the code that needs to use any of them than? Or would I want to require in the function itself so it makes sure it's there?

Comment: @wbinglee It's a tree based problem where the nodes can be be of different types and have different actions and properties but there is common processing in the parent node class that does most of the heavy lifting.

Comment: Why does that require the parent create children? The children will have all the functionality of the parent. I'm suspicious.

Comment: It's a code generator template parser it parses things into sections/elements of which there are different types. Most of the parsing logic is held in common but there is also custom logic for each type of element. I could probably do use a helper class but I wanted to see if there was a good way of doing it this way first since it seemed like a logical way. I'm new to Ruby (coming from C# where this is easy) so if this is just something that goes against Ruby conventions I'd love to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe in the comments, it's better to apply template design pattern for your application. And create your subclass instance outside of your parent class, it's not the responsibility of parent class.

Here is [sample implementation of ruby template design pattern](https://github.com/nslocum/design-patterns-in-ruby/tree/master/template_method). You will get a general idea of when to create your subclass and how the parent acts as a template class to do main process.

Of course, in ruby world, you can use code block instead of heavy template design pattern. You can pass a code block to your main method.

Comment: Thanks for the time you put into this answer. Unfortunately my use case is a bit more complicated as I am recursively creating objects in such a way that this design pattern wouldn't solve my problem. That being said the vibe I'm getting is that this is frowned upon in Ruby and that it would probably be better to refactor the parsing logic into helper module.

Comment: Marking as answer since event though it is not an exact answer to my question it pushed me in the right general direction and will be highly relevant to people who view this question in the future.